# Angular - Auto run command to add external package

Tags: angular, npm

My Angular 2+ project requires a third party package.
The package is installed by command likes that

```
npm install --save auth0-js
```

The command will download the package and store in folder "\node_modules".
Unfortunately, the "\node_modules" is not checked into source code control.

When someone get code, they need to run the `npm install` command again.

Ideally, I want when someone run the application, it will check all dependencies package and install automatically if it is not installed.

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

Which command are you using to run the application? Are you using Angular CLI command - ng serve to run the application in development mode?

If so, I suggest to modify package.json file as given below

```
"start": "npm install && ng serve"
```

This will download the dependencies before running the application using **npm start** command

Comment: thank for your help.
Could I do it just by "ng serve --open"?
I usually use that command to start the app

Comment: "start": "npm install && ng serve --open"

Comment: BTW, this may slow down the starting of the application because it will try to install npm libraries when you start the application each time